# How to add DNS record for a separate website in existing Google Workspace account

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, g-suite

I have a GoDaddy domain which is connected to a Google Workspace. Per their instructions, I have four A records named "@" that point to `216.239.3X.21` where X is 2, 4, 6, or 8. (per instructions [Google Workspace Admin - Configure A records](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2579934)) I have 5 MX records that point to `aspmx.l.google.com` and various alternates. And I have a CNAME record named `www` that points to ghs.googlehosted.com for Google Sites.

We're about to kickoff development of a Wordpress site with a contractor, and let's say it's hosted on a Google Cloud VM with a static IP a.b.c.d, and I want that site/IP to be available to the contractor under the name `dev.example.com`. Would I add an A record at GoDaddy named `dev.example.com` pointing to the address `192.0.2.42`?

It seems obvious, but I'm not sure if it conflicts in some way with the `@` records, and I do not want to interrupt access to my Google Workspace or drop any emails.

Comment: 1) I am not sure what/why you configured the four @ records at the zone root. What do they point to? The zone root typically points to a web server along with the name **www**. Since DNS domains are public information, just include the details in your question. 2) Regarding the resource record name **dev**, yes, create an A resource record with the IP address as the value. 3) When asking questions regarding DNS configurations, provide actual details. Small mistakes can take significant time to correct.

Comment: (1) I was instructed to do so by Google in the link above.  This is so that the naked domain "mydomain.com" eventually gets to the "www" hosted on Google Sites.
(2) That worked, thank you!
(3) I felt my question was almost too simple this time, but I'll keep that in mind next time..